# create a fallback for a request with workbox

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I am using workbox(v6) to make my app work offline. I am using the strategy **StaleWhileRevalidate** and I want to create a default response if the network and the cache fails. I've seen the setCatchHandler function that might do what I am looking for but I can't seem to find an example on how to use it.

How can I create a catchHandler for a requests whose URL matches a regex and respond with a custom response?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, you can use criteria other than a RegExp for routing, like [checking parts of the `url` object](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests#matching_a_route_with_a_callback_function) that is passed to the `matchCallback` in Workbox. But I'll provide an example that uses RegExps if you'd prefer.

```js
import {registerRoute} from 'workbox-routing';
import {StaleWhileRevalidate} from 'workbox-strategies';

const FALLBACK_HTML = '/fallback.html';
const CACHE_NAME = 'my-cache-name';

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => cache.add(FALLBACK_HTML)),
  );
});

const fallbackPlugin = {
  handlerDidError: async () => {
    const fallbackResponse = await caches.match(FALLBACK_HTML, {
      cacheName: CACHE_NAME,
    });
    return fallbackResponse;
  },
};

registerRoute(
  new RegExp('your-regexp-here'),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({plugins: [fallbackPlugin]}),
);
```

That example uses the [`handlerDidError`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins) callback method which was introduced in Workbox v6, and is appropriate if your RegExp route only matches HTML documents.

There are some other options depending on how much flexibility you need.

If you'd prefer maximum automation with minimal flexibility, you can use the [`offlineFallback` method from `workbox-recipes`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-recipes#offline_fallback).

If you'd like more flexibility in how your respond to failed requests, including fallbacks for other types of resources (like fonts, images, etc.) you can take a look at [these options from the Workbox docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#provide_a_fallback_response_to_a_route).

And if you prefer learning from videos, there's [Offline fallback page - Unpacking the Workbox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7gQg9JojGE).